# Legend customization for boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, boxplot

I have this boxplots graph, and then I am trying to plot 2 different points on top of it, of different colors, so that the user can see where they fall on the boxplot, plus compare them to each other. The problem is, i want the legend to show two dots with corresponding colors, and their IDs. Instead, the legend is showing the boxplot categories/colors. How can i override the legend to show only what i want? Here's my code:

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

data(airquality)
airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month,
                       labels = c("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"))
airquality$ID <-seq(1:nrow(airquality))
dataPoint <- airquality[11,]
dataPoint2 <- airquality[17,]
plt <- ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Month, y = Ozone, color = Month)) +
  geom_boxplot(show.legend=TRUE,outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(data = dataPoint, color='darkblue', aes(x = Month, y =    Ozone), size = 3,show.legend=TRUE) +
  geom_point(data = dataPoint2, color='darkred', aes(x = Month, y = Ozone), size = 3,show.legend=TRUE) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
plt
```

[image]

Comment: Not related to question, but if your x-axis is continuous I would change palette from discrete to something nicer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to plot figure like this would be:

- combine `dataPoint` datasets (using `rbind`). Like this you will only need to call one `geom_point`
- For boxplot use fill instead of color
- Define point colors using `scale_color_manual`

Code:

```
# Combine datasets
dataPoints <- rbind(dataPoint, dataPoint2)

# Plot
ggplot(airquality, aes(Month, Ozone, fill = Month)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_point(data = dataPoints, 
               aes(Month, Ozone, color = factor(ID)), 
               size = 3) +
    labs(color = "ID",
         fill = "Month") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("darkblue", "darkred")) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Result:

[image]

---

PS: I wouldn't add palette for month (fill) as it's this information is already shown on x-axis (redundant information). To remove fill legend you can add `guides(fill = FALSE)`.

---

Edit after OPs comment to use shape:

In case you want shapes instead of colors

```
ggplot(airquality, aes(Month, Ozone, fill = Month)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_point(data = dataPoints, 
               aes(Month, Ozone, shape = factor(ID)), 
               size = 3) +
    labs(shape = "ID",
         fill = "Month") +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 17)) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for the test-case I did, but here's a problem. Original graph that I posed (above) had boxplots with lines of different color, and no fill (white fill in the middle). That's how I need them displayed. Now, if both geom_point and geom_boxplot use "color" for diff. colors, then i can't remove the second parth of the legend by "guides(fill = FALSE)". Any tips on how to work around that?

Comment: @AnyaR in `geom_point` do this: `geom_point(data = dataPoints, aes(aes(Month, Ozone, fill = factor(ID)), shape = 21)`. For main `ggplot` change `fill = Month` to `color = Month`. Here we change fill to color. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! I almost figured this out on my own, but without shape=21 , points were coming out black disregarding my fill instructions. This little detail really helped, thank you! :)

Comment: Any chance you could recommend me how I could make the two points of different shapes (while the same color?). I tried to do shape=c(15,17) - for square and triangle, but this doesn't seem to work. :( Again, the challenge for me to show these two different shapes in the legend - next to ID. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: @AnyaR I edited my answer, please let me know if there's something else I can help you with :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would accomplish this by mapping the points to a different aesthetic. If `show.legend` is set to `FALSE` in that case, then the legends will show separately. You could also map to point shape, or any other aesthetic. Alternatively, you could map the `fill` of the boxplot geom, and map the `color` of the point geom.

For example:

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

data(airquality)
airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month,
                       labels = c("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"))
airquality$ID <-seq(1:nrow(airquality))
points <- c(11, 17)
airquality$Points <- NA
airquality$Points[points] <- c("Point a", "Point b")
plt <- ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Month, y = Ozone, color = Month)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(data = airquality[!is.na(airquality$Points), ], 
  mapping=aes(x = Month, y = Ozone, fill = Points), size = 3, shape = 21, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
plt
```

[image]